# nginx - can't reach status endpoint on localhost

Tags: nginx, curl, prometheus

I try to setup the nginx exporter for prometheus but have difficulties with the proper configuration of my nginx.

I have a default server block that redirects all requests from port 80 to 443. So all requests that fit no other server block listening on 80 should be redirected.
But my test curl request to status.localhost is also redirected to https (this one should not be redirected but return the nginx status page).

Content of redirect_80to443.conf

```
server {
    listen       80 default;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Content of monitoring_status_page.conf

```
server {

    server_name status.localhost;

    #listen localhost:80;
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;

    keepalive_timeout 0;

    access_log off;

    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;

    location /nginx_status {
        stub_status on;
    }
}
```

curl http://status.localhost/nginx_status

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective}\n http://status.localhost/nginx_status
(Source: [Get final URL after curl is redirected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3077316/7869582))

```
https://status.localhost/nginx_status
```

I have added the following as well

```
events {
    ...
    debug_connection 127.0.0.1;
}
```

In the logs I get

```
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 accept: 127.0.0.1:49742 fd:59
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 event timer add: 59: 60000:31696116931
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 reusable connection: 1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 epoll add event: fd:59 op:1 ev:80002001
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 http check ssl handshake
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 http recv(): 1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 https ssl handshake: 0x16
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 tcp_nodelay
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL server name: "status.localhost"
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL ALPN supported by client: h2
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL ALPN supported by client: http/1.1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL ALPN selected: http/1.1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL: TLSv1.2, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH Au=$
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 reusable connection: 1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 http wait request handler
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 malloc: 000055CC4997FD20:1024
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL_read: 0
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL_get_error: 6
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 peer shutdown SSL cleanly
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [info] 20873#20873: *790 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 127.0.0.1, $
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 close http connection: 59
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL_shutdown: 1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 event timer del: 59: 31696116931
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 reusable connection: 0
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 free: 000055CC4997FD20
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 free: 000055CC49993930, unused: 48
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 accept: 127.0.0.1:49742 fd:59
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 event timer add: 59: 60000:31696116931
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 reusable connection: 1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 epoll add event: fd:59 op:1 ev:80002001
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 http check ssl handshake
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 http recv(): 1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 https ssl handshake: 0x16
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 tcp_nodelay
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL server name: "status.localhost"
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL ALPN supported by client: h2
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL ALPN supported by client: http/1.1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL ALPN selected: http/1.1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL: TLSv1.2, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH Au=$
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 reusable connection: 1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 http wait request handler
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 malloc: 000055CC4997FD20:1024
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL_read: 0
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL_get_error: 6
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 peer shutdown SSL cleanly
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [info] 20873#20873: *790 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 127.0.0.1, $
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 close http connection: 59
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 SSL_shutdown: 1
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 event timer del: 59: 31696116931
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 reusable connection: 0
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 free: 000055CC4997FD20
2023/10/03 18:37:35 [debug] 20873#20873: *790 free: 000055CC49993930, unused: 48
```

Unfortunately with my current knowledge this does not really help me understanding how nginx decides for the server and location block.

Any idea what I do wrong or what I can do in addition to debug the issue?